# Cut and remove a string from another string in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a following string in a shell script.

```
var="rule:access=allow,default=default value,OTHER=0,SOMETHING=1"
```

I need to remove "default=default value" from $var.
Thus, the final string will become as follows:

```
var="rule:access=allow,OTHER=0,SOMETHING=1"
```

NOTE: The value after default may be anything. It could be "default=something else". It is not fixed. I need to remove that text.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer for revised question

```
$ echo "$var" | sed 's/default=[^,]*,//'
rule:access=allow,OTHER=0,SOMETHING=1
```

If we want to update the value of `var`, we use *command substitution*:

```
$ var="$(echo "$var" | sed 's/default=[^,]*,//')"
$ echo "$var"
rule:access=allow,OTHER=0,SOMETHING=1
```

### Answer for original question

#### Using bash

To remove `default=default value,`, use *pattern substitution*:

```
$ var="${var/default=default value,/}"
$ echo "$var"
rule:access=allow,OTHER=0,SOMETHING=1
```

This feature is documented in `man bash`:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>  **Pattern  substitution.**  The pattern is
>   expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion. 
>   Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern  against  its 
>   value  is replaced with string.  If pattern begins with /, all matches
>   of pattern are replaced with string.   Normally  only the  first match
>   is replaced.  If pattern begins with #, it must match at the beginning
>   of the expanded value of parameter.  If pattern begins with %,  it 
>   must  match  at  the  end of the expanded value of parameter.  If
>   string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the /  following 
>   pattern  may be omitted.  If parameter is @ or *, the substitution
>   operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant  list.  If parameter is an array variable
>   subscripted with @ or
>   *, the substitution operation is applied to each member of the  array  in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

#### Using sed

```
$ var="$(echo "$var" | sed 's/default=default value,//')"
$ echo "$var" 
rule:access=allow,OTHER=0,SOMETHING=1
```

Comment: The value after default is not always fixed. That is it can be anything. It can be default=something else. I need to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Assign this to `var` again.

```
echo $var|sed 's/default=default value//'|sed 's/,,/,/'
```

Last `sed` to take care of scenarios where `default=default value` is the first or last keyword in string.

Comment: The value after default is not always fixed. That is it can be anything. It can be default=something else. I need to remove that

Answer (score 0):

You can use two parameter expansions, one to get the stuff after the comma of `default=*` and one to get the part before `default`....

```
var="rule:access=allow,default=default value,OTHER=0,SOMETHING=1"

endo=${var#*default}
echo ${var/default=*}${endo#*,}

rule:access=allow,OTHER=0,SOMETHING=1
```

But `sed` might be easier...!